# JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser - Magento

Tags: javascript, facebook, magento

I have magento site, when I post my site link in Facebook status it populate my site and it show me warning error like

> JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser. You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.

I tried the following method but it not works.

> System -> Configuration -> Browser Capabilities Detection - > 
>   Redirect to CMS-page if cookies are disabled - No 
>   Show notice if JavaScipt is disabled - No

Please anyone help me on this - Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got the solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Turned out the authors of posts and pages where not adding Meta Descriptions. Make sure you have a proper Meta Description and the optional og:meta tag which is specifically for Facebook.

You can use the Facebook debugger to see what they are grabbing from your page and what you are missing.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/